# How do I add a delimiter to a menu list that's built using sprites?

Tags: html, css, menu, css-sprites, html-lists

I am making a menu with lists and sprites using this tutorial:
http://www.eccemedia.com/blog/blog.html&blogid=15

My menu is different from this one as the items are only text with graphic delimiters between them and I am having big problems getting this to work.

The first accepted comment from this question on Stack overflow doesn't work.
[How to include a separator image on a menu built with ul and li?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216197/how-to-include-a-separator-image-on-a-menu-built-with-ul-and-li)

Any ideas or examples on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use the CSS border property instead of an image? Seems like it would be easier.

Comment: Nah, the design requires a small graphic, and the most I can do with borders (and be compatible with most browsers) is lines as delimiters.

Comment: Maybe I should mention: I am doing this for a Wordpress site, so maybe I could do a no-link menu item and somehow replace that with my delimiter.

Comment: It may be easier if you post a screen shot of the nav design... but any html element can have a background image and you can set the x and y coordinates of that background image.

Comment: Actually, I finally managed to get it to work by using the advice in that Stack Overflow thread I posted. I'll post the official answer below. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Since I can't answer for 7 hours I better answer here:
I got it to work by using the advice from the Stack Overflow thread I posted (not sure why it wasn't working initially).

The code for the delimiter: 
**.menu ul li { float: left; background: url(delimiter.png) no-repeat 0 0; margin: 0 0 0 15px; padding: 0 0 0 25px; }**, while the sprite code from the article I posted goes into the **.menu li a** block.